# AWS X-Ray not showing the URL for all traces

Tags: c#, .net, aws-fargate, aws-xray

We are attempting to log our HTTP requests in a Fargate container to X-Ray. We see the health-checks getting logged so that is good. We also see that the traces for the other requests are there but X-Ray isn't showing any of the data. Below are some screenshots of what we are seeing:

[image]

[image]

Here is a diff of a health-check trace (red) and a real call (green)

[image]

After looking at all the AWS docs we are not doing anything odd, different, or unique, it is the exact same code. We are using C# running in .net 6 on a linux fargate instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any node in front of the Fargate node for your real calls? If there is a segment that is the parent of your Fargate segment, that is treated as the "Root" segment and only its HTTP metadata will be shown on the trace overview page. If that root segment doesn't have any HTTP details, unfortunately none will be shown.

As a workaround, you will need to remove the parent node of the Fargate service.

Comment: This is likely the issue. All the requests are coming from a service in another AWS account. Any idea what permissions I need or settings to change to make them show up?

Comment: To see the data from the other account and your account in one view, try cross-account tracing: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-crossaccount.html